# Detect the change of image

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I have an image that would change over time. I am using node js to try to detect whether the image has changed in a period of time. I send a request to acquire the image through axios and get the content length for checking. When the content lengths are the same, I assume the image did not change.
The problem now I see is that the change in content lengths may not reflect the change in image. May I know if there are other ways to detect the slightest change in image?

Comment: Why doesn't storing and checking with `==` work?

Comment: I tried storing the content lengths for comparison. The problem is that the difference in content lengths do not necessary refer to a change in image, at least when I double checked the images, they looked the same to me but the content lengths are different.
Do you rather mean to store the images in local and perform some file checksum?

Comment: Create checksum of the file(s) and compare them.

Comment: Good idea, in fact, I found a package online 'jimp', where it transform the images into hash. So my current approach is to check the hash everytime, so that when it changes, it reflects the changes.